# Can I use stripe checkout for subscriptions and destination charges (connected account)?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to use Stripe Checkout with a connected account. Where I would be able to create a subscription with **transfer_data["destination"]** and **application_fee_percent**.

The flow expected:

1. Create checkout Session (server side)

```
checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            success_url=domain_url + "/success.html",
            cancel_url=domain_url + "/canceled.html",
            payment_method_types=["card"],
            mode="subscription",
            line_items=[
                {
                    "price": priceId,
                    "quantity": 1
                }
            ],
            customer=customerId)
```

2. Redirect the user to Stripe checkout page
3. User enters his card details and subscribe

I tried with subscription_data["application_fee_percent"] and with Stripe-Account set.
But this is not working because customer is not found. Because I guess all customers are created on the platform account, not the connected account (that I want to conserve)

So my question: What's the way to do this with Checkout?

My other choice would be:

1. Collect card information to create a payment method
2. Create a subscription with application_fee_percent and transfer_data[destination].

But I would prefer to use Checkout for collecting card details which seems to me a better and easier user flow...

All advices will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought this was possible exactly as you hypothesized, but encountered the error:

```
Error: Can only apply a subscription application_fee_percent when the Checkout Session is made on behalf of another account (using an OAuth key or the Stripe-Account header).
```

which is what I assume you ran into. Undeterred I reviewed the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/subscriptions#transfer) and then the [changelog](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#8540---2020-05-20) (for `stripe-node`, which I use), and found the hint I needed:

> Add `transfer_data[amount_percent]` on Subscription

After I testing, I can confirm you *can* do this, you just need to use `amount_percent` ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-transfer_data-amount_percent)) using say 95% transferred instead of a 5% application fee (though be aware of how fees affect the funds flow).

**Bottom line, you can do this instead**:

```
checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        success_url=domain_url + "/success.html",
        cancel_url=domain_url + "/canceled.html",
        payment_method_types=["card"],
        mode="subscription",
        line_items=[
            {
                "price": priceId,
                "quantity": 1
            }
        ],
        customer=customerId),
        subscription_data={
          transfer_data={
            destination='acct_1234',
            amount_percent=95
          }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Is your test with the checkout create_session endpoint ?

Comment: It is a session, though this may be related to account configuration. Note that the docs list some restrictions so you may need to contact support: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/subscriptions#pricing

Comment: Sorry about the confusion here -- it looks like I'd joined a beta that affects this a while back and this might not be available to everyone just yet.

Comment: @JulienA Can you try this again and see if it works for you?

Comment: Yes Super! It works now. 
Thanks to have let me know!

Comment: Great, glad to hear it!