# How can I use Stripe checkout for subscriptions with prices created under connected accounts?

Tags: stripe-payments

This is a very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66723211/can-i-use-stripe-checkout-for-subscriptions-and-destination-charges-connected-a) except that a connected account has products and prices listed under their account rather than the platform. I'm running into the issue where the priceID isn't found although it's the same priceID on the connected account price.

How can I reference the priceID correctly from the connected account?

```
checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        success_url=domain_url + "/success.html",
        cancel_url=domain_url + "/canceled.html",
        payment_method_types=["card"],
        mode="subscription",
        line_items=[
            {
                "price": priceId,
                "quantity": 1
            }
        ],
        customer=customerId),
        subscription_data={
          transfer_data={
            destination='acct_1234',
            amount_percent=95
          }
        }
```

The error returned is "No such price". I've tried adding stripe_account in the checkout_session but the customer isn't found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a subscription using destination charges with a Product and Price that exists on the connected account.

Using `subscription_data.transfer_data.destination` means that you're creating a subscription using destination charges. For a destination charge, the charge occurs on the platform, and subsequently a transfer is made to the connected account for the amount specified. Because the charge occurs on the platform, the Product and Price used to create the Subscription should also exist on the platform (not the connected account).

If you're using subscriptions with direct charges, the charge occurs on the connected account. In this situation, the Product and Price must exist on the connected account (not the platform). You would then create the Checkout Session with the `Stripe-Account` header : https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication

```
checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        success_url=domain_url + "/success.html",
        cancel_url=domain_url + "/canceled.html",
        payment_method_types=["card"],
        mode="subscription",
        line_items=[
            {
                "price": priceId,
                "quantity": 1
            }
        ],
        customer=customerId),
        subscription_data={
          transfer_data={
            destination='acct_1234',
            amount_percent=95
          },
        stripe_account="{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}"
        }
```

You can read more about Connect here :

- https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges
- https://stripe.com/docs/connect/subscriptions